# Dojo Validation

Tags: javascript, dojo

Is there a way to stop Dojo from validating a textbox onBlur?

```
var textbox = new ValidationTextBox({
     placeholder : "search",
     name : "userQuery",
     required : true,
     missingMessage : "Please enter search term",
     onBlur : function(){
          //function to stop onBlur validation
     }
}, textboxNode);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, yeah. But I'm not sure when it would validate if it's not onBlur.

```
var textbox = new ValidationTextBox({
  placeholder : "search",
  name : "userQuery",
  required : true,
  missingMessage : "Please enter search term",
  validator: function(value, constraints){
    if (this.hasOwnProperty("focused")) { //true if textbox is loaded
      if (!this.focused) { // if textbox not focused (onblur)
        return true;  // considered valid
      }
    }
    return value !== ""; // test if value is empty
  }
}, textboxNode);
```

Comment: I upvoted, but I would suggest not using `textbox` within the validator callback. "this" will refer to the ValidationTextBox anyway, so you could use this.hasOwnProperty